# How to automatically set csrf token after sucessful login?

Tags: node.js, ajax

- I have used csrfProtection middleware using csurf module in all apis.
- How do I set it in cookie after successful login? I tried to set using
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken()); but the cookie is not set.
- Is there any way where I can set it inside api or after successful response from api inside ajax call?

Thanks.